# Windows Console Application on Mac/Linux? C++

Tags: c++, porting

I'm wondering if there's any way to make my Windows Console Application working on Mac and/or Linux. Like an easy way to port it which seems doubtful. The only way I can think of doing it is going on Linux/Mac computer and re-writing the code for that OS. I'm not even sure if there  is console applications for Linux or Mac but all I know is they have terminal/console windows which seems like I could put it through there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the complexity of your console application.

Does it use system calls? e.g. `System("pause")`

If it doesn't and you're using the basic STD libraries, the code should be portable, just needs to be recompiled.

Like i said, depends on the complexity of yor code.

EDIT:
The linux terminal works quite like the windows cmd (as the cmd is "a copy" of a unix terminal...)

Comment: `cmd` barely has any Unix shell functionality... It's just a bad command intrepreter, not even close to '"a copy" of'.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could try wine in Linux. http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Yeah I just thought of that. Probably work fine. Don;t know about Mac though.

Comment: It seems that wine also works on Mac. See [link](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/)